# document.querySelector is not a function - trying to replace # and links with social wrappers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some plain text inside of a `<p>` tag that I am trying to automatically find all links and all hashtags. I broken my script in two parts:

1. First apply the hashtag wrapper
2. Then apply the link wrapper
3. Execute function will run both functions above

I want to use pure JavaScript. What is the JS Equiv of getting HTML and replacing?

HTML

```
<p>
Thank you to @InstagramUsername for the award. I’m glad to contribute to the success of the property sector through the efforts of @AnotherUser.
#HashtagAwards #Another
</p>
```

JS

```
function getHashTags(){
 // Find # and wrap in <a>
    let hashTxt = document.querySelector("p")[0].html();
    hashTxt = hashTxt.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/explore/tags?q=$1'>$1</a>");
    hashTxt.html(hashTxt);
}

function getLinks(){
 // Find @ and wrap in <a>
    let linkStr = document.querySelector("p")[0].html();
    linkStr = linkStr.replace(/@(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/$1/'>@$1</a>");
    linkStr.html(linkStr);
}

function execute(){
    getHashTags()
    getLinks()
}

execute()
```

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost works, you were not setting the `innerHTML` correctly as `hashTxt` is not an element.

```
function getHashTags(){
 // Find # and wrap in <a>
    let hashTxt = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    hashTxt = hashTxt.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/explore/tags?q=$1'>$1</a>");
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = hashTxt;
}

function getLinks(){
 // Find @ and wrap in <a>
    let hashTxt = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    hashTxt = hashTxt.replace(/@(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/$1/'>@$1</a>");
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = hashTxt;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function getHashTags(){
 // Find # and wrap in <a>
    let hashTxt = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    hashTxt = hashTxt.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/explore/tags?q=$1'>$1</a>");
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = hashTxt;
}

function getLinks(){
 // Find @ and wrap in <a>
    let hashTxt = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    hashTxt = hashTxt.replace(/@(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://instagram.com/$1/'>@$1</a>");
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = hashTxt;
}

function execute(){
    getHashTags()
    getLinks()
}

execute()
```

```html
<p>
Thank you to @InstagramUsername for the award. I’m glad to contribute to the success of the property sector through the efforts of @AnotherUser.
#HashtagAwards #Another
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to place this in a JSFiddle but it only works for Anchor tags. Can you help? https://jsfiddle.net/Lepsy5pw/9/

Comment: Because you are overriding the values set by `getHashTags` with `getLinks`.